# Can I make my IP address look as if it is from another country, not from the US?

Tags: domains, ip-address

The top level domain .md is works as follows:

(A) If you are from the US, Canada, or a few other countries, you have to register .md domains through max.md for exorbitant prices, because they figure doctors don't know any better.

(B) If you are from anywhere else in the world, you get to register through nic.md for the much more reasonable yearly price of $39

So of course, I waited until I was on a trip to the Czech Republic, and then registered my .md domain when I was there.  However, now I want to renew my domain, but because I am back in the US, whenever I try to access my account throught nic.md, I am being redirected to max.md.  I am not going to be taking any trips overseas before my domain expires, so I wanted to know if there is a way to make my IP address appear as if it is coming from another country, like the Czech Republic, or elsewhere?

Comment: Sounds like a good reason to boycott .md altogether.

Comment: .md is the Internet country code top-level domain (ccTLD) for Moldova. What does it have to do with doctors?

Answer (score 6):

You'd need to use a proxy located at an ISP with a suitable IP to "fool" the origin detections. There's no way to spoof an IP address for TCP connections and get a useable connection, unless you have total control over all the routers between you and the target server.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to tunnel your network traffic over the [Tor Network](http://www.torproject.org/).

While it's mostly chance as to where you come out, odds are fairly good that you will get an endpoint in Europe or somewhere else in the world.

You can check to see the IP address of your endpoint by visiting a web site like http://whatismyipaddress.com, which also does a GeoIP lookup to determine where in the world your endpoint is located.

Answer (score 0):

1.) try using hotshield [a proxy software ] or anonymous browsing technique for it.

2.) Contact some friends living outside for the process,,, :P